# Expose statistics/logging remotely in Python

Tags: python, logging, jupyter-notebook, monitoring

I have Python scripts which run in the background (for a long time). Those scripts process data in some way and log output to the STDOUT - nothing fancy...

Playing around with [Dask](https://www.dask.org/) and its status page (which shows the progress if you run something in Jupyter for example). This got me thinking: is there is a module for *remote logging/stats* for Python scripts.

I am aware of remote debuggers, exception monitoring services, etc. I am just looking for something 'simple' what can be used within own script.

The idea:

Basically by loading this module, you now can connect to "your Python script" via the web browser. In the script you can push variable values to the UI (`remotelog.log('Done %d%%', done)`). Maybe even *logging as* data frame table, progress bar, graphs, etc. In some sense updatable logger, but not to STDOUT, but to a web UI with a fancy formatting and in place updates. So if, on line 10, you log a data frame, it will be updated in the web UI in the same spot. Maybe you could even define `N` x `M` grid and show specific output in a specific place.

Obviously one could implement web sockets or an API to the script, but it would be great if there was a plug and play module which that already and what only requires a *logging* call with some and it would update the web UI in the background.

Comment: I dont think this is "good question" for SO  but why reinvent the wheel ? Log to stdout and let the OS handle the logging to where ever/what ever format ? ryslog, fluentd, syslog-ng and what not ..  And pretty sure  there's client code for python for most of these ..

Comment: It's hard to log a graph in a useful STDOUT format. What I am suggesting here is not of course used in monitoring tools. See it as a progress bar which shown 4 bar with all thread running and their progress. One could say, why not just log thread id + percentage done to STDOUT... Well, progress bar gives a nice 'feel'. A graph has more details. Interactive table has better usability, etc.